# MySQL c# Winform - Create new database from dump file (localhost)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, localhost

I have a problem I need to solve, but not know how exactly. I have a WinForms application (C#) which connects to an online MySQL server - no problem there. In this application I have an option to make database backups (basically I dump this database to a local file on a computer).

I would like to locally "open" this backup on client's computer (to check some old data) - I don't want to make database restore on my server, because database must still be in use for other users. I want to make clean install of MySQL on a local computer and connect to it trough localhost (like I do for testing ), but I do not have physical access to that computer. I can send MySQL installer to my client, but how to go about automatically creating user with password and database from my dump file?

I know how to create a new database if it doesn't exist, but how to do it if it's clean install of MySQL server - no user and password yet.

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=????;";
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hello`;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Any help and direction is appreciated.

Regards!

Comment: Can't you just restore the database on your server under a different database name, and have the client connect to that?

Comment: I thought about that...but in theory multiple users from different computers could decide to look at their backup at the same time, so I would have to create multiple new databases or they would just override each others. That's why I would rather go with local...

Comment: Give each user a different database name. Honestly, introducing the scenario where a database is installed locally by a non-technical user seems to cause more trouble than it's worth unless it's explicitly planned for by, say, choosing a database that can be easily embedded in a process. Which MySQL isn't.

Comment: @millimoose Well I figured it really was too much hassle for non-technical user to set up mysql server. Wanted to write a script that would do the install and setup, but couldn't get it to work. So I will go with your suggestion with new databases (different names for users) on the server. After user will finish browsing the archived data, I'll just delete that database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand your problem. However,if you install a new `Mysql`，you can use `root` user through no database.
Anyway, one thing you need to know,Connect database must has `user` and `password` for `mysql` or `sqlserver`.

You may need to be more concise description of your problem.